# Slow response time from Spring Controller after upgrade to 4.3.2

Tags: spring-mvc

I've recently upgraded from spring 3.1.3 to spring 4.3.2.  After the upgrade I've noticed that my controller takes significantly longer to respond to requests.  This is using both tomcat and jetty, locally.  The controller is annotated with ResponseBody and returns json.  The Json object it's returning is pretty simple, a double and a few strings.

Looking into the tomcat logs, I can see that the old version takes around 3-5 ms to respond on average.  The new version is taking 130ms.

I've set timers at the beginning and end of my controller, and my application's code is taking around 3-5 ms with both versions of spring.  I'm assuming something's changed regarding the spring mvc application code itself.

Does anyone have any insights into what could have possible gone wrong or could suggest a profiler that can monitor spring itself?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked it down.  It wasn't spring 4 (I figured as much) but rather adding Bcrypt as the passwordEncoder that caused the discrepancy in speed.